# I have a problem trying to get a friendly url to work and The htaccess rule does not work for me

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, post

Problem with friendly url.
I have a wordpress website.
The url to obtain a post is: https://xxxxxx.bienvenidoal.club/ficha-villa-revisada/?id=64d3434c2ef7ca0038c707e7 where: the ¿id= identifies the post.
This url works and brings me the post. I want to rewrite that url into a friendly one: https://xxxxxx.bienvenidoal.club/propiedades/villa_aldan/64d3434c2ef7ca0038c707e7
I have this RewriteRule in htaccesses:
RewriteRule ^properties/(.*)/(.*)$ reviewed-villa-file/?id=$2
In this second group of characters, I pass the id= to the unfriendly url.
And testing this configuration with: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ I get the correct answer. But, in practice it gives me page not found.
The next and definitive step is to use a friendly url without the id at the end and find a way to pass that information to the unfriendly url, looking like this:
https://xxxxxx.bienvenidoal.club/propiedades/villa_aldan /

I need the friendly url to bring me the specific post

Comment: The problem is that WordPress uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine what content to show - and _internal_ URL rewriting does not change that value. You'll need to look into WordPress' own mechanism for URL rewriting, https://www.regur.net/blog/wordpress-url-rewriting/